# Where are the "teams" in the GitHub hypermedia API?

Tags: github-api, octokit

Using [Octokit](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb), I can traverse link `rels` to get to "organization" and "members," but I can't seem to find "teams" anywhere.

I can get a representation of an org, but the link `rels` don't include anything for team

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: token $OAUTHTOKEN" https://api.github.com/orgs/MY_ORG
```

gives me

```js
{
    "login": "…",
    "id": …,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/MY_ORG",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/MY_ORG/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/MY_ORG/events",
    "members_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/MY_ORG/members{/member}",
    "public_members_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/MY_ORG/public_members{/member}",
    "…": "…"
}
```

Octokit nets similar results:

```ruby
client = Octokit::Client.new access_token: ENV['GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN']
my_org = client.org 'MY_ORG'
my_org.rels
```

```ruby
{:self_url=>"https://api.github.com/orgs/MY_ORG",
 :repos_url=>"https://api.github.com/orgs/MY_ORG/repos",
 :events_url=>"https://api.github.com/orgs/MY_ORG/events",
 :members_url=>"https://api.github.com/orgs/MY_ORG/members",
 :public_members_url=>"https://api.github.com/orgs/MY_ORG/public_members",
 :avatar_url=>"…",
 :html_url=>"https://github.com/MY_ORG"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [developer documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/) for [Organizations](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/) you'll see that the endpoint is `/orgs/:org_name/teams`. To get an individual team you want `/teams/:team_id`.

---

I see now that you're using an OAuth Token (from the Authorizations API). You likely don't have the proper scopes set for the token. Take a look at the [list of scopes](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes) and note that you probably at least nead `read:org` to see your teams.

Comment: Yes, this shows me where I could find the IDs of my org's teams, and where I can fetch representations of the teams by ID, but I can't find a link relation or URI template.

That is, I can hard-code to the URL `/orgs/:org_name/teams` and the hard-code templating a `/teams/:team_id` URL, but I would prefer hard-coding only to link relations and a single base URL. I can get from orgs to repos, events, and members, but teams seem to be missing.

```sh

Comment: Thanks, @sigmavirus24. I updated my token to have every privilege, but again found no teams in the org. I did, however find that I can get to `teams` from `repos`. Even though the documentation shows a `/teams/:team_id/`, in actuality, this must be prepended with a repo path.